# add parameter to function in c# and js

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, parameters

i need to give parameter to a function, i'm not sure how to do so
i need to add a parameter in my read function so i can use the same function several times, i added a parameter called val and tested if its equal to the value i need to call a function, now my problem is that i don't know how to add that parameter in the read function in my script (objhandler.read('one') ?? )

in my .js file i have this :

```
 var objHandler = new Interact(); // create an object the the handler class in javascript file. using this object, we can access the methods in the handler class.

function SayRead() {
    try {
        objHandler.Read(function (serverResponse) {
            if (serverResponse.error == null) {   
                var result = serverResponse.result;
                if (result.length > 2) {
                    SessionStore.loadData(Ext.decode(result));
                }
            }
            else {
                alert(serverResponse.error.message);
            }
        }//eo serverResponse
        ); 
    } //eo try
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

SayRead();
```

in my .ashx.cs file i have :

```
public class Interact : JsonRpcHandler
{
    [JsonRpcMethod()]
    public string Read(string val)
    {
        // Make calls to DB or your custom assembly in project and return the result in JSON format. This part is making custom assembly calls.

        clsDBInteract objDBInteract = new clsDBInteract();
        string result;
        try
        {
            if (val == "one")
            result = objDBInteract.FetchSessionsJSON();
            //if (val == "two") result = objDBInteract.FetchJobsJSON();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

P.S: i use jayrock library

thanks.

Comment: edited my code,thx, if u have more questions let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think more details would be helpful. I assume you are using a library / toolkit like jayrock. Please let us know.

You might want to try

```
objHandler.Read('one', function (serverResponse) {
```

This is AFAIK the way Jayrock would create the function.

Comment: thanks,yes i use jayrock, i tried this ,it doesnt work,and i dont get an error, the wierdest is that my code (in the question) work!!i dont understand how since the condition if (val=='one' is not satisfied

Comment: any specific details u need,just let me know.i really appreciate ur help,thx

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the proxy as generated by Jayrock.
Download xxx.ashx?proxy and see - you should find something like 
... this[m[0]] = function /* Read */ (val, callback) ...
If not, what do you instead find? What Jayrock version do you use?

Comment: im sorry im giving u hard time, but i dont know how to download my file.ashx,newbie here :p .jayrock version 0.9 (if my memory is correct)

Comment: ive done it :) found this :      this[m[0]] = function /* Read */ (callback)
    {  
        if (self.kwargs) return rpc(new Call(0, { }, callback));
        return rpc(new Call(0, [ ], callback));  
    }

Comment: Strange. The parameter "val" is not offered in your proxy, whereas it should. I assume you made everything to ensure cache is deleted (both client cache and ASP Output Cache) after you added the function parameter? Then you could take the downloaded proxy js-code and modify it, writing
this[m[0]] = function /* Read */ (val, callback) { if (self.kwargs) return rpc(new Call(0, {val: val}, callback)); return rpc(new Call(0, [val], callback)); } -- but that is now really ugly :-)

Comment: yes cache is a good idea..but im not sure how to delete it, i usullay just close everything and open it again,lame i know :(

Comment: Restart of the server (IIS service if nothing else helps), SHIFT-Reload on the client.

Comment: it worked,thanks a lot...i spent the whole day struggling with this when it was only cache!!

Comment: would u take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505673/grid-not-populated-with-data-json-error-extjs-jayrock) prblem please,ty